# Spark AR CAMERA zoom in and zoom out

Tags: spark-ar-studio

I am new to spark AR, I have seen the documentation but unable to find support where you can achieve below queries.

1. Zoom in and zoom out camera towards a 3D object
2. Rotate around a 3D object

It says camera coordinates are read only, you cannot change its position on an event.

Any pointers or insights on this guys?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot move the actual camera in Spark, because that is mapped to the device camera position (aka your phone).

However, if you wish to scale the video feed, you could get the camera extract texture, apply it as a material to a canvas or plane, and then scale the plane in order to create a "zoom" effect.

You can also rotate and move 3d objects by editing their transform properties, like so:

```
let myObj = Scene.root.find('my-object');
myObj.transform.x = value;
myObj.transform.y = value;
myObj.transform.z = value;
myObj.transform.rotationX = value;
myObj.transform.rotationY = value;
myObj.transform.rotationZ = value;
myObj.transform.scaleX = value;
myObj.transform.scaleY = value;
myObj.transform.scaleZ = value;
```

etc.